# .NET Date variable specification & locale

Tags: vb.net, date, globalization, literals

I set the date variable

```
Dim myDate as Date
myDate = #5/15/2013#
```

Does this work always at runtime, no matter what is the system locale settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "work"? Note that this is VB-specific; C# doesn't have date literals, for example.

Comment: I mean when compiled application is run, the second line above won't throw error ever, no matter what regional settings are used.

Comment: If there is a better, recommended way to set a date in code, I'd like to know it. Like DateSerial(2013, 5, 15). I'm looking the fastest way to do it.

Comment: Well we still don't know what you actually want to do. Do you *always* want the Gregorian calendar to be used? What about which "kind" of `DateTime` you want? I very much doubt that this will be a performance bottleneck either way...

Comment: I am just trying to ask if I can in VB.Net set the date as mm/dd/yyyy (#5/15/2013#) or do I need to check at runtime the system locale settings and use in some locales mm/dd/yyyy (#15/5/2013#) instead?

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear that you were only interested in the system settings in terms of the *format*. No, that part's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3eaydw6e.aspx):

> You must enclose a Date literal within number signs (# #). You must specify the date value in the format M/d/yyyy, for example #5/31/1993#. This requirement is independent of your locale and your computer's date and time format settings.
>
> The reason for this restriction is that the meaning of your code should never change depending on the locale in which your application is running. Suppose you hard-code a Date literal of #3/4/1998# and intend it to mean March 4, 1998. In a locale that uses mm/dd/yyyy, 3/4/1998 compiles as you intend. But suppose you deploy your application in many countries. In a locale that uses dd/mm/yyyy, your hard-coded literal would compile to April 3, 1998. In a locale that uses yyyy/mm/dd, the literal would be invalid (April 1998, 0003) and cause a compiler error.

So, the answer to your question is YES, it will always work at runtime, and NO, you do not need to change this for the locale settings of the computer.

Do keep in mind that date literals are somewhat frowned upon.  They are supported in VB.Net as a backwards-familiarity thing from VB6.  They don't even exist in other .Net languages like C#.  If you have to hard-code a specific date, you are much better off using `DateTime` with separate parameters, such as:

```
Dim myDate as DateTime
myDate = new DateTime(2013,5,15)
```

Also note that `Date` is just a VB.Net alias to `System.DateTime`, again there for backwards familiarity from VB6.  It doesn't matter which you use, they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, that does not work in a country such as Canada where the standard is dd/MM/yyyy.  The best way to globalize your application would be to use DateTime.ParseExact and/or DateTime.TryParseExact

```
        Dim tempdate As DateTime

        tempdate = DateTime.ParseExact("05/20/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I was thinking like you at first, but surprisingly date literals are always in M/d/yyyy format.  See my answer.

Comment: Very true.  I didn't know about the # # being a strict format, but assuming you are working with data entered in a text field, or imported string data, using .ParseExact and .TryParseExact for known data formats are reliable ways to make sure date parsing is handled correctly regardless of your locale.

Comment: Good info. In this case I was looking just how to hardcode a date but in practice more often the date comes entered and this helps.